# Using Resharper to Identify Instances of IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Can [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (v 7.1.3) help identify code that does not apply the "using" keyword when instantiating objects that implement IDisposable (i.e. SqlConnection, StreamReader)?

Comment: More specifically, the Code Analysis part of Visual Studio 2012 can, specifically it is warning CA2000.

Comment: Note that none of the answers to the duplicate question seems to indicate that FXCop can do this. And this is true, FXCop does not warn about this. It does, however, warn about types containing fields that are IDisposable not implementing IDisposable itself, but it was the Code Analysis engine in VS2012 that added the support for checking if you correctly call Dispose on the object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ReSharper alone cannot do this.

FXCop cannot do this either, unfortunately. FXCop can warn about types that contain fields of types that implement IDisposable, but the type that contains them does not implement IDisposable. This is not what is being asked for here.

What you need is Visual Studio 2012 and then enable the Code Analysis engine to work its magic on your code. Make sure to enable a ruleset that contains the rule.

[image: enable code analysis]

Specifically you want to enable the CA2000 warning:

[image: CA2000]

after enabling this, and writing code like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
        }
    }
}
```

you get this:

> d:\Dev\VS.NET\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs(14): warning : CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'Program.Main(string[])', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'stream' before all references to it are out of scope.

**Note**: This will in some cases create both false negatives and false positives. First, the rule detects, and does not warn about the fact that you *return* such an object.

However, in the method where you get back the object, it will only call out the fact that you don't dispose it in some cases.

Specifically, this will create the warning:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stream = CreateStream(); // warning here
}

private static MemoryStream CreateStream()
{
    return new MemoryStream();
}
```

whereas this will not:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stream = GetStream(); // NO warning here
}

private static MemoryStream GetStream()
{
    return new MemoryStream();
}
```

The rule seems to detect that **Create** is a prefix for a factory method, so it falls upon the caller to dispose of the object, whereas **Get** is not such a prefix, so it falls upon the method being called to dispose of it, but since it returns the object, it doesn't have that responsibility either.

Comment: Another false positive is when instantiating an `IDisposable` in a `using` statement.

Comment: can we find memory leak code using visual studio? I am not able to understand 3rd part tools.

Comment: Finding memory leaks using static code analysis requires good tools, and even those won't be able to find everything in this day of reflection and service containers. Your best option is those 3rd party tools, such as Jetbrains dotMemory and similar tools.